# ERC20 Implemented, mint not successful

Tags: erc-20

The transaction shows up on my metamask account for minting but the balance of my new coin is zero. When I looked up the new coin, it was able to identify the token symbol and decimal. Why isn't the balance updating?

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.7.0;

contract BestCoin {

    uint constant private MAX_UINT256 = 2**256 - 1;
    // The keyword "public" makes variables
    // accessible from other contracts
    address public minter;
    uint256 public tokenTotalSupply = 0;
    mapping (address => uint) public balances;



    // coin name
    function name() public view returns (string memory) {
        return "TheBestCoin";
    }

    // coin symbl
    function symbol() public view returns (string memory) {
        return "TBC";
    }

    // divide token amount
    function decimals() public view returns (uint8) {
        return 8; // 100000000
    }

    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
        return tokenTotalSupply;
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns(uint256 balance) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value); // TODO must throw
        balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balances[_to] += _value;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balances[_from] >= _value);
        balances[_to] += _value;
        balances[_from] -= _value;
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256 remaining) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        return true; // TODO
    }

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);

    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);

    // Events allow clients to react to specific
    // contract changes you declare
    event Sent(address from, address to, uint amount);

    // Constructor code is only run when the contract
    // is created
    constructor() public {
        minter = msg.sender;
    }

    // Sends an amount of newly created coins to an address
    // Can only be called by the contract creator
    function mint(address receiver, uint amount) public {
        require(msg.sender == minter);
        require(amount < 1e60);
        balances[receiver] += amount;
        tokenTotalSupply += amount;
    }

    // Sends an amount of existing coins
    // from any caller to an address
    function send(address receiver, uint amount) public {
        require(amount <= balances[msg.sender], "Insufficient balance.");
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        balances[receiver] += amount;
        emit Sent(msg.sender, receiver, amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: `2**256` overflows to 0, so you may as just do `MAX_UINT256 = uint256(-1)`.

Comment: `The transaction shows up on my metamask account for minting but the balance of my new coin is zero` - please share the details of your transaction (function name, parameter values, etc).

Comment: A possible cause is that send and mint do not generate Transfer event.

Comment: Apparently

    require(amount < 1e60);

does not make sense.
What should it be expected to do?

The result of such a comparison is quite unpredictable because what the compiler is going to translating it is difficult to understand.